# How would I stack an SVG circle on top of another one using D3?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

So I have the following code:

```
let connector = g
          .append("circle")
          .attr("cx", positionElement.x)
          .attr("cy", positionElement.y)
          .attr("r", 4)
          .attr("class", "connector");

let connectorPlus = g
          .append("circle")
          .attr("cx", positionElement.x)
          .attr("cy", positionElement.y + 10)
          .attr("r", 4)
          .attr("class", "connector");
```

These circle SVG's appear on top of a rectangle. I am trying to make it so that my connectorPlus circles appear on top of my original connector circles.

How would I achieve this in D3? As you can see, I am currently trying to apply an addition of 10 units on top of each elemement, but this does not seem to be working.

Again, I am trying to stack each of the four connectorPlus circles about 10 pixels up from the the original connector circles.

Any ideas on this are very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I simply used the position of each initial circle position, and then added or subtracted 10 to the relevant axis that each one of them sat on. Example below, and the positions within the 'position' variable, grabbed from somewhere else within the code:

```
let connectorPlus;

if (position == 'bottom') {
    connectorPlus = g
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", positionElement.x)
    .attr("cy", positionElement.y + 10)
    .attr("r", 4)
    .attr("class", "connector");
}
if (position == 'top') {
    connectorPlus = g
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", positionElement.x)
    .attr("cy", positionElement.y - 10)
    .attr("r", 4)
    .attr("class", "connector");
}
if (position == 'bottom') {
    connectorPlus = g
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", positionElement.x)
    .attr("cy", positionElement.y + 10)
    .attr("r", 4)
    .attr("class", "connector");
}
if (position == 'left') {
    connectorPlus = g
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", positionElement.x - 10)
    .attr("cy", positionElement.y)
    .attr("r", 4)
    .attr("class", "connector");
}
if (position == 'right') {
    connectorPlus = g
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", positionElement.x + 10)
    .attr("cy", positionElement.y)
    .attr("r", 4)
    .attr("class", "connector");
}
```

Comment: All this can be just `.attr("cx", positionElement.x + (position === "right" ? 10 : position === "left" ? -10 : 0))` and `.attr("cy", positionElement.y + (position === "bottom" ? 10 : position === "top" ? -10 : 0))`. So, in total, just 6 lines of code.